# Why json response includes backward slashes in web api response

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Hi i have a web api with get method and returns custum json format:

Problem: Why json value contains "/ characters

Returns:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "code": 200,
  "data": "\"{\"token\":\"E013D7050A8C4447989651D29AD3E637\"}\""
}
```

My return code:

```
return new HttpResponseBody(true, message, (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, data != null ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data) : data);
```

My reponse class;:

```
 public class HttpResponseBody
{
    public bool success;
    public string message;
    public int code;
    public object data;

    public HttpResponseBody(bool success, string message, int code, object data)
    {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static HttpResponseBody Success(object data = null, string message = "")
    {
        return new HttpResponseBody(true, message, (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, data != null ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data) : data);
    }

    public static HttpResponseBody Error(System.Net.HttpStatusCode code, string message)
    {
        return new HttpResponseBody(false, message, (int)code, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is escaping the quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are serializing two times the same object. The first time you are serializing it manually using:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```

Then you are returning another object that the framework itself will serialize, this will cause it to escape characters inside the string object called `data`.

Do not manually serialize your data, let the framework do the heavy lifting:

```
return new HttpResponseBody(true, message, (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Escaping quotes

The backslashes are escaping the quotes inside the string. Otherwise, the quotes would act like normal and end/begin a string.