# Swift ObjectMapper: How to parse JSON with backslash

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have tried pretty much all the potential solutions on stackoverflow and so far no luck,

This is my json response:

```
[
    "{\"id\":5,\"request_id\":\"rqst5c17fc752d44f1.15452158\",\"business_name\":\"611 Solutions\",\"business_email\":\"611thesolutions@gmail.com\",\"title\":\"123ABC - TESTING\",\"details\":\"Package is fragile, please haul with care\",\"load_description\":\"Royal Timber\",\"amount_offered\":\"2500\",\"pickup_address\":\"123 Colliumeal Dr, Fort Wayne, Indiana\",\"dropoff_address\":\"647 Airportway, Chicago, Illinois\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-12-17 19:43:49\"}"
]
```

Notice there are backslashes within the key and values of the json and my parsing is failing, this is how I am parse the json:

```
Alamofire.request(JOB_REQUEST_BASE_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[JobResponseDataObject]>) in

    log.debug("Fetching Job Requests...")

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let responseArray) :
        log.debug(response.debugDescription)
        log.debug("Sucessfully fetch job requests")
        log.debug("Job request counts: \(responseArray.count)")
        completionHandler(JobRequest.fetchJobRequest.Response(jobResponses: responseArray), nil)

    case .failure(let error) :

        log.debug("Fetching error: JobRequest")
        log.debug(error.localizedDescription)
        completionHandler(nil, .FailedToFetchEmptyJobRequests)

    }
}
```

I have also tried fetching the pure string using `.responseString` and doing `let json = response.result.value?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")` and mapping it like so `let jobs = Mapper<JobResponseDataObject>().map(JSONString: json!)` so far no luck too. Please help

Thanks

Comment: The response is an array containing one item which is another JSON string.

Comment: We can help you parse this, but the right solution is to fix whatever service is delivering this so that it doesn’t include another JSON string inside the array. Do you have the ability to change the web service?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no, this response is from my teammate, it is from php script, is there a 3rd party api that he can use?

Comment: @Rob can you please guide me on how to parse this using object mapper? thank you

Comment: If it's a kind of demo/small-app then you can keep on messing with response to make a valid json but if it's anything more than a small project then it should be fixed on the backend side immediately.

Comment: @BrendonCheung - If it’s PHP code that someone in your team has the ability to fix, you definitely should do that. It makes no sense to write convoluted iOS code to handle a server-side mistake. And, if and when you get around to writing the Android client, they’re going to have to program around the same bug. That’s just silly. You should really go back to your team lead and encourage them to fix the web service. We shouldn’t program around bugs if possible, but rather just fix the root problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
if let str = responseArray.first as? String , let data = str.data(using:.utf8) {

   do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self,from:data)
    }
   catch {
    print(error)
   }
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let requestId, businessName, businessEmail, title: String
    let details, loadDescription, amountOffered, pickupAddress: String
    let dropoffAddress, timestamp: String
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to remove backslashes - it's just serilized one more time, that means it needs to deserialize back.
Look at: [Why json response includes backward slashes in web api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256500/why-json-response-includes-backward-slashes-in-web-api-response)

Just make a Data object from the string item:

```
let data = stringItem.data(using: .utf8)
```

then decode normally using JSONDecoder.